# c3p0 with amazon postgres RDS

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-rds, c3p0

I'm trying to connect to RDS using c3p0, when not using RDS the code works but fails with RDS,
pure java with DriverManager can create a connection leading me to believe the issue is with c3p0

```
connectionPool.setUser(user);
connectionPool.setPassword(password);
connectionPool.setJdbcUrl(jdbc);
try {
    Connection con = connectionPool.getConnection();//fails after several seconds
    con.isValid(1);
    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc, user, password);
    con.isValid(1);//true
    con.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but c3p0 blames postgres

> java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
>       at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
>       at my code, the "connectionPool.getConnection()" line
>   Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
>       ... 13 more
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2852)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1875)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:37)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:221)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1853)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:405)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:382)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:904)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.(NewPooledConnection.java:120)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:240)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>       at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>       at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>   Blockquote

I tried using connectionPool.setDriverClass, it didn't help
I'm using java11 and c3p0 from hibernate-c3p0 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/5.4.2.Final, tried to update to latest beta, it didn't help

Comment: You might check whether the version of the JDBC driver you are using is consistent with the RDS postgres version, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876269/could-not-open-connection-caused-by-this-resultset-is-closed

Comment: (it'd be the Postgres JDBC driver version you'd want to look into. and you'd want to try Connecting directly from a test program, first without even c3p0 and then with. it's hard to debug through a framework layer.)